# Central lock button blinking on Peugeot 407 when car is locked

Tags: peugeot

When I lock my car, the central lock button (the one with padlock) on the panel starts blinking with a 1 sec. rate. I have check if the boot is closed, and it is (if it wasn't, it would also show an error on the display.

It's not that long ago since I bought, but I can't recall seeing this blinking earlier. Can anyone check if theirs are blinking as well, or does anyone know what's wrong, if there is anything wrong at all?

Panel: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been told that this is normal. That it is blinking when car is locked.